# Show $\sin(a+b)+\sin(a+c)+\sin(b+c)-\sin a-\sin b-\sin c-\sin(a+b+c)=8\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2} \sin \frac{c}{2} \cos \frac{a+b+c}{2}$

Tags: trigonometry

My first thought was to use the sum-to-product formulas on the left side. This got me as far as
$$
4\left(\sin\frac{a}{2}\sin\frac{b}{2}\sin\frac{c}{2}+\cos\frac{a}{2}\cos\frac{b}{2}\cos\frac{c}{2}\right)\cos\frac{a+b+c}{2}-2\sin(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2}+c)\cos(\frac{a}{2}+\frac{b}{2})
$$

After I gave up here, I tried some other things: using the sum identities on the left side, using the half-angle identities on the right side. These approaches seemed even less helpful. At least with the first idea, I saw bits of the expression that I was looking for.

Comment: Hint: Since $ \sin (a+b+c) = 2 \sin (a+b+c)/2 \cos (a+b+c)/2$, move it over to the RHS and factor out $\cos(a+b+c)/2$. Then, look at what's left on the LHS, how can we force out more $ \cos (a+b+c)/2$ from the terms that remain? Hopefully we can factor it out (like it is on the RHS).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider that $$\sin(a+b)-\sin c=2\cos\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)\sin\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)$$

So if you pair off all the first six terms on the LHS in the same way you get a common factor of $$2\cos\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)$$

And the other factor is $$\sin\left(\frac{a+b-c}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{b+c-a}{2}\right)+\sin\left(\frac{c+a-b}{2}\right)-\sin\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right),$$
where the last term comes from splitting $\sin(a+b+c)$ into half angles.

This remaining factor can be collected pairwise as $$2\sin\left(\frac b2\right)\cos\left(\frac{a-c}{2}\right)+2\cos\left(\frac{a+c}{2}\right)\sin\left(-\frac b2\right)$$
$$=2\sin\left(\frac b2\right)\left[-2\sin\left(\frac a2\right)\sin\left(-\frac c2\right)\right]$$

And hence the result.